# Why do i get an error when i try to bind my UDP socket to a port with SFML?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, udp, sfml

I'm currently building a network prototype for SFML using UDP. I've created an application in which you can choose to be the server or the client. So, usually I start up 2 instances of the application, letting one be the server and the other be the client. I'm connecting to my local IP 127.0.0.1.

About 20 minutes ago, this EXACT code worked and I had no problems with it. I didn't change anything, but this code does not work anymore, and the program crashes when I call `socket.bind()` for the server. Client-side, no errors show up.

This is done in C++.

Does anyone know a possible cause for this? As far as I know, the port is not in use, either.

My client code:

```
void runUdpClient(unsigned short port){
    sf::IpAddress server;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "Type the address or name of the server to connect to: ";
        std::cin >> server;
    } while (server == sf::IpAddress::None);

    sf::UdpSocket socket;

    sf::Packet clientSendPacket;
    std::string packetSendContent = "Packet data from the client";
    clientSendPacket << packetSendContent;
    if (socket.send(clientSendPacket, server, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;
    std::cout << "Message sent to the server: \"" << packetSendContent << "\"" << std::endl;

    // Maak variabelen
    sf::IpAddress sender;
    unsigned short senderPort;
    sf::Packet clientReceivePacket;
    std::string clientReceiveContent;
    if (socket.receive(clientReceivePacket, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        return;

    clientReceivePacket >> clientReceiveContent;
    std::cout << "Message received from " << sender << ": \"" << clientReceiveContent << "\"" << std::endl;

}
```

My server code:

```
void runUdpServer(unsigned short port){
    sf::UdpSocket socket;

    if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
        return;

    std::cout << "Server is listening to port " << port << ", waiting for a message... " << std::endl;

    sf::Packet serverReceivePacket;
    std::string serverReceiveContent;
    sf::IpAddress sender;
    unsigned short senderPort;

    if (socket.receive(serverReceivePacket, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "Error receiving packet for server";
        return;
    serverReceivePacket >> serverReceiveContent;
    std::cout << "Message received from client " << sender << ": \"" << serverReceiveContent << "\"" << std::endl;

    sf::Packet serverSendPacket;
    std::string serverSendContent = "Packet data from server";
    serverSendPacket << serverSendContent;
    if (socket.send(serverSendPacket, sender, senderPort) != sf::Socket::Done)
        std::cout << "Error sending packet from server";
        return;

    std::cout << "Message sent to the client: \"" << serverSendContent << "\"" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Define 'crashes'. What was the error?

Comment: It just returns.

This part is where it fails:

if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
    return;

Comment: So print the error and tell us what it was. There is no useful information here yet.

Comment: It does not print an error because it just catches it. It returns out of the function when the socket fails to bind.

Comment: It does not print any error because you failed to write your code correctly. Printing your own error message and suppressing the real error is a complete waste of time. The error after any system call that failed is available in `errno` and can be printed as text with `perror()`. This is rather basic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your server code, the `if` statements are missing braces, so you are ALWAYS executing `return` as soon as `socket.bind()` exits, whether it succeeds or fails.  This code:

```
if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
    return;
```

Is the same as this code:

```
if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
return;
```

Which is logically equivalent to this code:

```
if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done) {
    std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
}
return;
```

Whitespace formatting is not important to C and C++.  To perform multiple statements inside the body of an `if` block, you need explicit braces:

```
if (socket.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
{
    std::cout << "Error binding socket for server";
    return;
}
```

Same with the `if` statements for your server's calls to `socket.receive()` and `socket.send()`.

Your client code is not outputting any error messages if `socket.send()` or `socket.receive()` fail, those `if` statements are performing single statements in their body (namely, just `return`), so braces are optional.

Answer (score 0):

Your server most likely shut down without closing the port properly.
If you wait a few minutes the port will be free to use again (takes about 2-3 minutes on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, might be different depending what OS you use)

Alternatively you can change the port you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the port did not help for me. I've waited for about 15 minutes but that did not help. Im using windows 10. I'm considering restarting my pc soon to see if it helps.

Comment: You could try and do socket.bind(sf::Socket::AnyPort) and see if that works. If it does, you can then get the port by calling socket.getLocalPort().

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the formatting of the `if`s and the `return`s. After hitting <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+K</kbd>, the code got formatted again and it worked.

Comment: Formatting des not change the semantics of executable code. You fixed something else.